# How to check if any of the options are selected in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

How will I check if any of the three items are selected. I have two lists of options looks something like this:

```
  <div class="fruits">
        <select>
            <option>apple</option>
            <option>orange</option>
            <option>banana</option>
            <option>hello</option>
            <option>Bye</option>
        <select>
    </div>

   <div id="criteria">
        <select>
            <option>fruits</option>
            <option>in season</option>
            <option>expensive</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

I want to make the "criteria" Id options read only if any of the three options apple, orange , banana are not selected. Multiple options in class "fruits" can be selected, like the user can select apple or hello, hello or bye and apple and banana.

What could be the possible logic. I have tried few approached like maintaining an object with key as apple, orange and banana and value are their count of click and if count is 0 of all the keys then I would hide the other option tag.

I tried other approaches as well.
The code for this one is here:

```
<script>
    var count = 0; 
    fruitsList  = document.getElementsByClassName("fruits"); 
    var countObj = {
            apple: 0,
            orange:0,
            banana:0, 
        }   
    for(var i = 0; i<= fruitsList.length-1 ; i++ ){
        fruitsList[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        \* have to grab the value of the elements because the list of elements is generated by PHP and there will be plenty of elements *\
    var threeOption = this.getAttribute("value");
             if(fourOption == 'apple' || fourOption == 'orange' || fourOption == 'banana'){
    if(this.selected == true){
                    countObj[fourOption]++;
                    }
                else if(this.selected == false){
                    countObj[fourOption]--;
                }
                else{
                    countObj[fourOption]--;
                }
            }
    for (var key in countObj) {
                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(countObj, key)) {
                    var val = countObj[key];
                    if(val>0){
                        count = 1; 
                    }
                }
            }
    if(count==1){
                for(var i = 0 ; i<=5 ; i++){
                    document.querySelectorAll("#criteria option")[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
                    }
                }
           else{
       for(var i = 0 ; i<=5 ; i++){
    document.querySelectorAll("#criteria option")[i].setAttribute("disabled","true");
        }
       }
     });
    }
</script>
```

The options should reappear if again any of apple, orange or banana is reselected and should become readOnly if they are not selected.
Please suggest a logic. Please let me know if I have mistaken anywhere, I will be happy to correct myself in future.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use [**getComputedStyle**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Not tested but you can try this

```
function setElement(){
// pass the element
window.onscroll = function(){scroll(element)};
}

function scroll(elem){
eHeight = window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue("height");
        //Rest of the code
}
```

Comment: How can I use getComputedStyle in this context? Is there anyway to get the current state of the element like weather it is selected or not.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. using jQuery I was able to get the current selection and then checked if the current selection contains apple, orange or banana. 
Here is the link to the appropriate function in JQuery API documentation.

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/